# Joining in laravel with two connection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, laravel-5

I have two connection in laravel, and I want to connect both

I tried like this

```
$response = DB::connection('connection1')->table('table1 as t1');
$response->DB::connection('connection2')->leftJoin('table2 as t2', 't2.t1_id','=','t2.id')
->get();
```

But query fails, how to join this, please help.

Just like I can do in mysql like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyDatabaseOnDB1].[dbo].[MyTable] tab1
INNER JOIN [DB2].[MyDatabaseOnDB2].[dbo].[MyOtherTable] tab2
    ON tab1.ID = tab2.ID
```

How can do this in laravel.

Please comment, If you give me negative votes please..

Comment: Both connection indicate different database?? and both databases are on same server?

Comment: both DB are in same server in my case. sharing same credentials, just DB name are changed.

Comment: You seems to be conflating databases and database connections. You do not need two connections to deal with several databases. You cannot perform a query across two separate connections. Queries are performed inside the database server not inside the Laravel code. Two connections is best suited for when you have two physically separated databases.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively I am doing like this way.

```
$database1 = Config::get('database.connections.connection1.database');
$database2 = Config::get('database.connections.connection2.database');

$response = DB::table($database1.'.table1 as t1')
->leftJoin($database2.'.table2 as t2','t2.t1_id','=','t2.id')
->get();
```

Comment: In your solution your $database2 connection will return the same database. You still didn't used any middleware to change dynamic database for connection $database2

Comment: Route::group(['middleware' => 'change_database'], function()
      {
            // your code goes here...
      });

Comment: As you said you want your database need to be dynamic.

Comment: I don't think any middleware is needed. All that is needed is to have variables, as this demonstrates, that allows specifying the database (and schema for other vendors like sql server or postgres) and use them appropriately on the single connection.  If two physically separate databases are required, then two connections will be required and you'll have to filter and join in software instead of in SQL; avoid that when you can.

Answer (score 0):

To join two different database tables you have to use query builder in laravel 5.2

I think this will help you and working fine in my case.

```
  $sql="select * from database1.table1 left join database2.table2 on database2.table2.table2Id=database1.table1.table1Id" 
      $data = DB::select($sql);
```

Hope it will help you...

Comment: just give the database name static and try to find the query is running or not in my case it is working and i am using this in my application

Comment: Is there other way to use join by connection not by database directly, Actually Database name are dynamic.

Comment: you can not query both database at once like we do with eloquent in laravel you have to use query builder to use this and you can get datbase name from either session or from env file where you declare the names

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot, now I made query as I want. Its similar as you guide me but dynamic as I want.